# Appender settings in orbeon log4j config file doesn't work

Tags: logging, configuration, log4j, orbeon

I set my Orbeon log4j.xml file to make backups when log has size more than 5MB. When my log file reach this size, it is truncated but I don't see any backup file. Where it is? How can I make configuration if I want to my backup has file name with current date?

```
<root>
    <priority value="info"/>
    <!--<appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>-->
    <!--<appender-ref ref="ChainsawAppender"/>-->
    <!--<appender-ref ref="SingleFileAppender"/>-->
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>

<appender name="RollingFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="../logs/orbeon.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="3MB"/>
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="200"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false" />
    <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by changing `../logs/orbeon.log` to use an absolute path. Then the backups should be in the same directory. You also need to specify that `RollingFileAppender` must be used:

```
<root>
    <priority value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
```